# Коллеги кто знает/пользовался и может посоветовать нормальный мультиплатформенный supplicant для 8021x?

Tags: linux, windows, безопасность, macos, freeradius

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, имеется зоопарк из разных железок разных вендоров и как следствие разных ОС, внедряю 8021x port-based аутентификацию, младшему персоналу требуется настроить всех клиентов и чтобы не настраивать каждый раз по разному, требуется какой-нибудь не родной клиент который подходил бы для всех вышеупомянутых ОС. Спасибо.